# Unable to read the project file "libcocos2d.vcxproj" in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cocos2d-x

I used `cocos new GameDemo -l cpp -d D:\project\CocosProject` to create a cocos2d-x project in Windows 10, then I open project with VS2015, but I got a lot of errors and my cocos2d-x version is 3.11.1.

[image]

Here is part of error output

```
D:\project\CocosProject\GameDemo\cocos2d\cocos\2d\libcocos2d_win10\libcocos2d.vcxproj : error  : Unable to read the project file "libcocos2d.vcxproj".
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.Cpp.Current.targets(108,3): The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Application Type\Windows Store\10.0\Platforms\ARM\Platform.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

I've been working on this problem for 3 days, I installed, and uninstalled again and again. But I still got this problem. I tried `devenv.exe /setup /resetuserdata /resetsettings` and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you do a custom install to make sure you have all the VS languages, libraries, SDKs you need?  The default install is missing a lot of features.  Note that you can run the installer again to add features without uninstalling.

Comment: @daves  I installed Windows SDK indepent of VS2015, but WindowsTargetPlatformVersion configure in libcocos2d.vcxproj file is 10.0.10586.0, I don't know where set it. Also I am confused why Cocos2d-x need Universal Windows App Development Tools. I still can't make project done.

Comment: @rencheng.yang Have you tried to run `proj.win32` project ?

Comment: I met too much problem, and I afraid I was on a wrong path and would go further, thus, I reinstall again.

Comment: @rencheng.yang now working after reinstallation ?

Comment: @AbhishekAryan I added latest information in answer list.